# UIImage not being displayed in UIImageView on iPhone5, yet works in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, ios-simulator

I am relatively new to iPhone development, but have been a windows programmer for 20 years+.

I was recently asked to develop an app that would read external sensor data, create an in-memory heat-map image and then render the image to the screen.

Xcode v4.6.2 - iOS 6.1 Simulator/iPhone 5.

(After some effort) I was successful. On the simulator the sensors are read and the image file built and returned from my library as a CGImageRef. I then use the following code to load it into a UIImageView object within my view controller. Like this:

```
// Line edited to remove transcription error
CGImageRef cgimg = [sensor getSensorImage : 200 : 200]; 
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage : cgimg];

imageView.image = image;
```

*This works just fine in the 6.1 simulator*, the heat map looks correct and is rendered to the screen. When I connect an iPhone 5 and run on that, *nothing is rendered*. The UIImageView remains grey. There are no errors that I can find, no exceptions thrown. The image object is not null, and all lines of code are executed successfully.

Calling **setNeedsDisplay** does not appear to help either.

I've been scratching my head on this one for days.

Is it possible that:

(a) The hardware provisioning profiles are incomplete? or (b) The UIImageView in the view is somehow disconnected from the code references when I run on hardware?

Comment: CGIImageRef is a pointer itself by its nature, so here CGIImageRef* cgimg asterics is not necessary. And in last line you are trying to init UIImage not with CGIImageRef but with pointer to CGIImageRef. Compiler should complain on that. Pay attention on compiler warning.

Comment: You are misspelling CGIImageRef, should be CGImageRef!

Comment: And you should have this compiler warning 'Incompatible pointer types sending 'CGImageRef *' (aka 'struct CGImage **') to parameter of type 'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *'); dereference with *', provided you've corrected spelling of CGIImageRef.

Comment: Thanks I will check for a compiler warning, and re-examine the return type from my method. 

...and update the spelling. (I had to manually transcribe everything as the Mac is not connected to the network at my work place).

Comment: Oops that was actually a transcription error on my part, when I built the code there were no warnings - so I went looking for what level warnings were set to. I will edit the code above and remove the '*'. 

It's still not working on the hardware though :(

Comment: It is strange it works on simulator. Suppose you should blame other part of your code.

Comment: Try to save image on disk with following lines of code: NSString *cachesDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"]; NSString *pathname = [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"]; [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pathname atomically:YES]; That catch pathname in debugger and look at file save in Finder (on simulator). You will see what really you have. You can do same on real device. But to see file you have to store your apps data to Mac with Organizer of xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out (to use the Apple parlance) that it was a de-allocation error on my part.

At the end of the image creation routine, I was trying to free *all* the resources that were used in building the image, leaving just the final image itself.

One of these was the pixel buffer of an intermediate image. Once I removed the dealloc on that, the image started to show up in on the iPhone.

I have been running the application for several hours, with no indication of a memory leak. I guess ARC is taking care of it.

Strange how there was no reported error or warning.

Just one of the many differences between *simulated* and *real* hardware.